# split circle sprite into colorized pieces with own colliders in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a rotating circle sprite in Unity.

```
private void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 10 * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

and in my `Start` method I want to split this sprite into several pieces. I put in an array of colors as a parameter.

```
private void SetColors(Color[] colors)
{
    // divide into color pieces
}
```

For example I pass in *red, blue, green, yellow* the circle should look like this

[image: circle]

The amount of possible colors is unlimited.

The circle itself got a circle trigger attached. When detecting a trigger collision I want to detect which color was hit.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.gameObject == ball)
    {
        // Color hitColor = the color that was hit
    }
}
```

Is it possible with a simple circle sprite?

**Update:**

Maybe this problem might be easier to solve if I say that when the circle gets hit by something it's always at the top of the circle

[image: collision]

I might calculate the current hit color by using the rotation speed over time.

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to utilize [Colliders ContactPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContactPoint.html) and [GetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixel.html) to get the color of the pixel at the point of the collision. You need to use colliders and not triggers to do this however. That being said, without digging into it to much, I think the most normal method would just be instantiating a gameobject for each piece of the circle.

Comment: What part do you want with this answer: making a plain circle Sprite to get divided and automatically colorized by code _or_ fetching what is the correspondent color depending on which part of the circle was touched?

Comment: I need both parts. I want to colorize the circle and I want to get the collision detection. But I will update my question

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late but I found this interresting so:

This component is placed on an empty `GameObject` within a `Canvas`. It is responsible for creating and updating the segments (and for the simulation controles the cursor object with a circle collider)

```
public class CircleController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RectTransform rectTransform;

    public List<Color> InitialColors = new List<Color>();


    private List<Circlesegment> segments = new List<Circlesegment>();

    public Circlesegment circleSeggmentPrefab;

    public float firstSegmentAngleOffset = 0f;

    // maximum vertices to use for the circle
    // equally spread over all segments so not always uses all of them
    public int totalMaxVertices = 50;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        // if 0 start first segment at top
        var startAngle = firstSegmentAngleOffset;
        var anglePerSegment = 360f / InitialColors.Count;
        var verticesPerSegment = totalMaxVertices / InitialColors.Count;

        foreach (var initialColor in InitialColors)
        {
            var segment = Instantiate(circleSeggmentPrefab, transform);
            segment.Initialize(this, initialColor, verticesPerSegment, rectTransform.rect.width / 2f, startAngle, anglePerSegment);

            segments.Add(segment);

            startAngle += anglePerSegment;
        }
    }

    // Used this to simulate the collisions using the mouse
    private CircleCollider2D cursor;

    //used this to simulate the collision using mouse
    private void Update()
    {
        if (!cursor)
        {
            cursor = new GameObject("cursor simulator", typeof(CircleCollider2D)).GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
            cursor.radius = 10;
            cursor.enabled = false;
        }

        cursor.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            cursor.enabled = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            cursor.enabled = false;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveSegment(Circlesegment segment)
    {
        segments.Remove(segment);
        Destroy(segment.gameObject);

        if (segments.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("GameOver!");
            return;
        }

        var startAngle = firstSegmentAngleOffset;
        var anglePerSegment = 360f / segments.Count;
        var verticesPerSegment = totalMaxVertices / segments.Count;

        foreach (var circleSegment in segments)
        {
            circleSegment.AnimateTowards(verticesPerSegment, startAngle, anglePerSegment);

            startAngle += anglePerSegment;
        }
    }
}
```

---

This component is attached to the `circleSegmentPrefab`

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(RectTransform))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(EdgeCollider2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Image))]
public class Circlesegment : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Image image;
    [SerializeField] EdgeCollider2D collider;
    [SerializeField] Rigidbody2D rigidBody;
    [SerializeField] RectTransform rectTransform;

    [SerializeField] private int _segments;
    [SerializeField] private float _startAngle;
    [SerializeField] private float _segmentAngle;

    private float _radius;
    private CircleController circleController;

    public Color Color;

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        circleController.RemoveSegment(this);
    }

    public void Initialize(CircleController controller, Color color, int segments, float radius, float startAngle, float segmentAngle)
    {
        Color = color;
        circleController = controller;
        _radius = radius;

        if (!image) image = GetComponent<Image>();
        if (!collider) collider = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();
        if (!rigidBody) rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (!rectTransform) rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        image.color = color;
        rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(radius * 2, radius * 2);

        UpdateSegment(segments, startAngle, segmentAngle);
    }

    public void AnimateTowards(int segments, float startAngle, float segmentAngle, float duration = 1f)
    {
        StopAllCoroutines();

        StartCoroutine(AnimateTowardsroutine(segments, startAngle, segmentAngle, duration));
    }

    private IEnumerator AnimateTowardsroutine(int segments, float startAngle, float segmentAngle, float duration)
    {
        var timePassed = 0f;
        var currentStartAngle = _startAngle;
        var currentSegmentAngle = _segmentAngle;

        while (timePassed <= duration)
        {
            var lerpFactor = timePassed / duration;

            UpdateSegment(segments, Mathf.LerpAngle(currentStartAngle, startAngle, lerpFactor), Mathf.LerpAngle(currentSegmentAngle, segmentAngle, lerpFactor));

            timePassed += Mathf.Min(duration - timePassed, Time.deltaTime);
            yield return null;
        }

        UpdateSegment(segments, startAngle, segmentAngle);
    }

    public void UpdateSegment(int segments, float startAngle, float segmentAngle)
    {
        _segments = segments;
        _startAngle = startAngle;
        _segmentAngle = segmentAngle;

        var arcPoints = new List<Vector2>();
        var angle = 0f;
        var arcLength = segmentAngle;

        if (!Mathf.Approximately(Mathf.Abs(segmentAngle), 360)) arcPoints.Add(Vector2.zero);

        // calculate procedural circle vertices
        for (var i = 0; i <= segments; i++)
        {
            var x = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * _radius;
            var y = Mathf.Cos(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle) * _radius;

            arcPoints.Add(new Vector2(x, y));

            angle += (arcLength / segments);
        }

        if (!Mathf.Approximately(Mathf.Abs(segmentAngle), 360)) arcPoints.Add(Vector2.zero);

        image.fillAmount = arcLength / 360f;
        rigidBody.rotation = startAngle;
        collider.points = arcPoints.ToArray();
    }

    // For testing
    [ContextMenu("UpdateSegment")]
    private void UpdateSegment()
    {
        UpdateSegment(_segments, _startAngle, _segmentAngle);
    }

    //For testing
    [ContextMenu("AnimateTowards")]
    private void AnimateTowards()
    {
        AnimateTowards(_segments, _startAngle, _segmentAngle);
    }
}
```

---

Demo

[image]

`Image` settings on the prefab

[image]

[image]

looks shitty because of the default `Knob` texture .. you should use a better quality circle texture.