# Circle automatically divided and colorized according to input on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

i’m trying to make a fraction calculator simulator kinda like the pic below [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vLGI.png) so when input is changed it automatically change according to the input are there any way to do this?

i have tried to search tutorials but only found using CSS on web and the only way I thought was making all possibles manually

Comment: Would this help as a startpoint? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506251/split-circle-sprite-into-colorized-pieces-with-own-colliders-in-unity I know your use case is a bit different but I think you could re-use parts of it ;)