# creating a circle with 2d triangle prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to divide a circle into n number of parts and place a triangle with correct rotation there, so that all triangles added up can look like a circle. I have tried to do so with following code:

```
public class DivideCircleWithTriangles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int numTriangleDivisions = 8; // Change this to modify the number of triangles
    public GameObject trianglePrefab; // Assign your triangle prefab in the Inspector

    private void Start()
    {
        DivideAndPlaceTriangles(transform.position, 1f);
    }

    private void DivideAndPlaceTriangles(Vector3 center, float radius)
    {
        if (numTriangleDivisions <= 0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Number of triangle divisions must be positive.");
            return;
        }

        float angleStep = (2f * Mathf.PI) / numTriangleDivisions;

        for (int i = 0; i < numTriangleDivisions; i++)
        {
            float angle = i * angleStep;
            Vector3 point = center + new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius, Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius, 0f);

            Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, angle * Mathf.Rad2Deg);

            // Instantiate triangle
            GameObject triangle = Instantiate(trianglePrefab, point, rotation, transform);
 
        }
    }
}
```

It works to some extent, but I get empty spaces and spikes. Can anyone solve the code or tell me a way to achieve perfect circular area with triangles? Or should it be done with any other shape other than triangle?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50606756/creating-a-2d-circular-mesh-in-unity

Comment: [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506251/split-circle-sprite-into-colorized-pieces-with-own-colliders-in-unity) did a bit more than you ask for but it should get your started